# Variable getting error it is undefined

Tags: php, variables, pdo, permissions, frameworks

I am getting the error: (I searched for this error and saw nothing comparable)

`Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$permissions in`

For this line of code: `$permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);`

It is from this:

```
public function hasPermission($key) {
        $group = $this->_db->get('groups', array('id', '=', $this->data()->group));

        if($group->count()) {
            $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);

            if($permissions[$key] == true) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I call for it like so:

```
if($user->hasPermission('User')) {
    include 'navUser.php';
}
```

I am unsure what I am doing wrong. This is from a framework and it works on my other sites, the only difference from this site is the folder I am trying to call it from is within a sub-folder, which the other sites the pages were within the root.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The answer would depend on what `$group` has as it's value. My guess would be that `$this->_db->get('groups'....etc...);` is returning no rows and so the call to `$group->first()` is returning an empty object, one without a `permissions` property.

Comment: I get bool(false) when I var_dump this: `var_dump($user->hasPermission("User"));`

Comment: @RiggsFolly How is this a duplicate? I have a specific issue that I cannot figure out??